# Make SSH tunnel in android

Tags: java, android, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I have project that need to open connection via ssh tunnel , in android I have used jSch library I have succeed to make connection server but I stacked ! How can I make webview to load url via SSH connection?

void  go() throws  Exception {

```
    int tunnelLocalPort= 8080;
    String tunnelRemoteHost="localhost";
    int tunnelRemotePort=339;

    Properties config =  new java.util.Properties();
    session = jSch.getSession(username ,host , 22);

    session.setPassword(password);
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "Yes");
    config.put("Compression", "yes");
    config.put("ConnectionAttempts", "2");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    session.setPortForwardingL(tunnelLocalPort,tunnelRemoteHost,tunnelRemotePort);

    Log.d("ssh" ,"connect");
    webView.loadUrl(sessionId);

}
```